# Gitlab: tokenless push to github repo?

Tags: github, ssh

I've set up an account on github. I've uploaded my ssh public key.

On github I've created a new empty repo.

In my local environment I've set up git to manage a project. Now I'd like to push the project to github.

When I do 'git push -u origin main', I am asked for my username and password.

The first time I did this I received a message that directed me to the use of tokens. So I created a token. However, now I have to input my token ever time I push to github.

Up until recently I was able to push without entering a password/token thanks to the use of ssh keys. Is it possible to still use this?

If so, how do I get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure username and password by default and it wont ask you again and again, but make sure the username has access to that repository.

Comment: Is there documentation for how to create this kind of configuration? If so, do you where it is?

Comment: Hope this url helps you:- https://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/first_time.html